# Matrix-pair permutation puzzle

Tags: matrices, permutations, puzzle

Here's a puzzle. We have an $N \times N$ table. Inside each cell we write two numbers, $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$, where $i,j$ denote row and column index.  All numbers $A$ and $B$ are integers, $A,B \in [1, N]$. The constraints are as follows

1. For each row $i$, all numbers $A_{ij}$ are different
2. For each row $i$, all numbers $B_{ij}$ are different
3. For each column $j$, all numbers $A_{ij}$ are different
4. For each column $j$, all numbers $B_{ij}$ are different
5. There are no two cells, for which the pair $(A,B)$ would be the same

Example solution for $N=3$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1,1 & 2,2 & 3,3 \\
2,3 & 3,1 & 1,2 \\
3,2 & 1,3 & 2,1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Question**: Determine for which $N$ there exists a solution. For those $N$ for which the solution exists, propose an algorithm to find 1 viable solution.

Comment: The pair "$(A,B)$" for one or two cells is slightly inaccurate, so we want to avoid $(A_c,B_c)=(A_d,B_d)$ for two different cells $c=ij$ and $d=i'j'$? And which are the own trials to solve the puzzle?!

Comment: It is some permutation of indexes with no fix point, you can do that by iterating cycles for each raw

Comment: @ToniMhax I have written a computer code to check this numerically. I have high suspicion that there are no solutions for N=4 and N=10, but I get a correct solution for N=3. That is why I ask

Comment: @dan_fulea I believe that point 5 is sufficiently clear. All cells must have a different pair written in them, so there are no two cells that would have the same pair. Can you elaborate why you believe point 5 is inaccurate? My own attempt was to apply a bunch of permutations on paper for N=10, it did not work, then to write a computer code, it also did not find a solution. I have no idea why for some $N$ there exist solutions and for other's there do not. Maybe my code is wrong, I can post if it helps, but it is brute force search, so hard to screw that up :)

Comment: The pair $(A,B)$ is in your example explicitly the pair $$\left(\ \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\2&3&1\\3&1&2\end{pmatrix}\ ,\ \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\3&1&2\\2&3&1\end{pmatrix}\ \right)$$and i do not see any cells. Please always insert the own attempts in the posted question, it is then easier for a potential answerer to continue on the same line, or to fill in the details or improve the situation where the attempts do not lead to a solution. In this case, there is an obvious try, as in the example, to consider $A$ corresponding to a cycle permutation of order $3$, then search for an other one for $B$.

Comment: I believe this is known as a Graeco-Latin Square. It is known that the only values for N where a solution does not exist are 2 and 6. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square)

Comment: Indeed, it isn't trivial. @Aleksejs Fomins

Comment: @InterstellarProbe this is indeed what I was looking for. If you post as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a Graeco-Latin Square. The only values for $N$ that do not have a solution are 2 and 6. Here is the wikipedia article for it:

[Graeco-Latin Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square)

There is also a proof for the non-existence of a solution for $N=6$ here:

[Proof of non-existence for the $N=6$ case](http://web.pdx.edu/~caughman/Kalei501.pdf)